# mysqli, How to fetch data column wise, I need MAX, AVG of columns?

Tags: mysql

I know we can use use MAX with column name, I have more than 70 columns, now question is I have two tables Columns of table 'USERS' is more than 70, I am taking only 3 for example:

**USERS**

```
USER_ID | NAME | GAME_1
 1      | A    | 23    
 2      | B    | 45    
 3      | C    | 45
```

**FRIENDS**

```
USER_ID | FRIEND_ID
1       |  2
1       |  3
```

Now if user '1' is logged in I need MAX and AVG of his friends.

**I am using:**
Query:

```
SELECT *  
FROM  `USERS` INNER JOIN 
      `FRIENDS` ON USERS.USER_ID = FRIENDS.FRIEND_ID 
where FRIENDS.USER_ID = 1
```

Now I need the **MAX** and **AVG** value of the result set. MAX from GAME_1 values, AVG of GAME_1 values and so on.

Reading about mysqli_fetch_field.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(AGE),AVG(AGE) FROM ... GROUP BY USER_ID`

Comment: this question does not show any research effort. It is clear that it is not useful.

Comment: I know about using MAX with every column, but using if for 70 Columns :) should I use this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(U.AGE) as MaxVal,AVG(U.AGE) as AvgVal
FROM  `USERS` U INNER JOIN 
      `FRIENDS` F ON U.USER_ID = F.FRIEND_ID 
WHERE F.USER_ID = 1
GROUP BY F.USER_ID
```

Comment: I know about using MAX with every column, but using if for 70 Columns :) should I use this? I dont want to use this style? query will be to long...

Comment: @JyotiPrakash: What else do you prefer to select the maximum and average values?

Comment: I need the MAX and AVG value of the result set. MAX from GAME_1 values, AVG of GAME_1 values and so on for GAME_2, GAME_3, GAME_4...

Comment: @JyotiPrakash: I mean, what can you use other than `MAX` and `AVG` functions to find maximum and average values?

Comment: We both know we have to use MAX and AVG with Column name, I am building a game and I don't want to change the query every time I add a new column, my question is, Writing MAX(Col1), MAX(Col2).... MAX(Coln) its no point. Is there a way I can get the columns value in array and use 
max — Find highest value for (PHP 4, PHP 5)

Comment: If you need to add columns to you database then you should take another look at your database design. You should have a separate scores table with user_id, game_id , and score. This way you can keep on adding games without having to add columns.